# Realm - Cannot query objects inside an Activity/Fragment when these Objects were created on the Test Class @Before method

Tags: android, junit, realm

When trying to create mock data in the `@Before` method of a JUnity4 test case, I'm not able to query the created data using Realm inside the Activity that was being tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that JUnity tests start the activity Before the `@Before` method runs.

This means that the data created on the test case wasn't available when the Activity started.

Solution:

1. Tell the test runner to not start the Activity before the tests run.

   ```java
   @Rule
   public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = 
       new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);  // NOTE THE FALSES
   ```
2. Start the activity manually after creating the data you want.

   ```java
   @Before
   public void before() {
       // This must be the same config as the one being used by your app in the test.
       final RealmConfiguration configuration =  new RealmConfiguration.Builder(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
         .name(TaskerApplication.REALM_FILE)
         .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
         .schemaVersion(0)
         .build();

       realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration);
       realm.beginTransaction();
       createdObject = realm.copyToRealm(new AnyRealmObject());
       realm.commitTransaction();

       // Launch the Activity manually
       activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN));

       // Object will be available when queried from the Activity. 
   }
   ```